How to control a VMware vSphere/ESXi virtual machine using Python and get the VM screen?
I'm trying to control a virtual machine (and get the screen contents) using Python, which is hosted on VMware vSphere/ESXi. How do I do it?
I haven't found a proper way to do it, and tried something already. How do I do it correctly?
I've already tried getting a ticket using vm.AcquireTicket('webmks') and monkeypatching VNCDOTOOL to connect to a websocket server with autobahn (likely with a wrong approach):
# monkeypatch vncdotool for websockets
__old_vncdotool_factory_connect = vncdotool.client.factory_connect
def __vncdotool_factory_connect(factory: vncdotool.api.VNCDoToolFactory, url: vim.VirtualMachine.Ticket, *_):
    
    factory = autobahn.twisted.WrappingWebSocketClientFactory(factory, url.url, reactor=vncdotool.client.reactor)
    __old_vncdotool_factory_connect(factory, url.host, url.port, socket.AF_INET)

vncdotool.client.factory_connect = __vncdotool_factory_connect
vncdotool.api.factory_connect = __vncdotool_factory_connect

def __vncdotool_parse_server(server):
    logger.debug("Received server parse request with ticket %s", server)
    return (socket.AF_INET, server, -1)

vncdotool.command.parse_server = __vncdotool_parse_server
# ...
ticket = get_webmks_ticket(self.vSphere, self.vm)
self.client = vncdotool.api.connect(ticket)
# Some time later:
self.client.keyPress('enter')

This doesn't work - when I call any VNCDOTOOL function (such as self.client.keyPress('enter') or self.client.captureScreen('test.png')), the thread freezes, and the action (in this case, pressing the enter key and capturing the screen) doesn't happen. I expected it to, well, perform the action. I also get this in the logs:
[2024-09-28 12:30:59,201] [twisted] [_legacy.py:147] INFO: Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WrappingWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x7f36d224ea10>
[2024-09-28 12:30:59,201] [twisted] [_legacy.py:147] INFO: Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WrappingWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x7f36d224ea10>
[2024-09-28 12:30:59,204] [twisted] [_legacy.py:147] INFO: Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WrappingWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x7f36d224ea10>
[2024-09-28 12:30:59,204] [twisted] [_legacy.py:147] INFO: Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WrappingWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x7f36d224ea10>

